# Capturing paste into ListBox listbox event only works when ListBox item is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm creating a UserControl which is basically just a listbox which allows users to paste in strings (and it will do some validation to check they are valid IDs for the system).

However, the problem is that I can't capture/register/handle the paste event unless an item in the listbox is selected. Here's the user control code-behind:

```cs
public partial class MyListUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MyList), typeof(List<string>), typeof(MyListUserControl), new PropertyMetadata());

    public List<string> MyList
    {
        get => (List<string>)this.GetValue(MyListProperty );
        set => this.SetValue(MyListProperty, value);
    }

    public MyListUserControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        //This does nothing
        this.listBox.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Paste, this.PasteExecuted, this.PasteCanExecute));

        //This only triggers when items already exist in listbox and an item is selected
        this.listBox.PreviewKeyDown += this.ListBox_PreviewKeyDown;

        //this doesn't appear to help
        this.listBox.Focus();
    }

    private void ListBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key == Key.V)
        {
            var clip = Clipboard.GetText();
            this.MyList = //do something with data from clipboard
        }
    }

    private void PasteCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //this would actually contain logic to check if clipboard contains valid data
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }

    private void PasteExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var clip = Clipboard.GetText();
        this.MyList = //do something with data from clipboard
    }
}
```

If I pre-populate the listbox with some dummy data, and then select an item, my `ListBox_PreviewKeyDown` method is triggered and behaves as expected.

How can I ensure this works even when the listbox is empty?

Note: if the listbox contains items but none are selected, I am still unable to capture and handle the ctrl+v/paste event.

Comment: Its because you can't select listbox itself, thus it wont capture any key events. They're going to the window I assume. I'll check if I can find a nice fix

Comment: Is it an option to catch the keydown on window level? As long as you're using the application the window will have focus so it will receive the events. The problem with listview is it will never have focus itself, its items might but that's it.

Comment: It might be an option... It would probably make the reusability of this usercontrol a bit less smooth, but I could deal with that.

Comment: I don't think the usercontrol will get the event either sadly (you could test it of course), maybe it could find the window with relativesource or something? That way you could keep the code contained to the usercontrol at least

Comment: That's a good thought, I'll see if I can register the parent window's event to a method in the user control... It sounds like that might have unfortunate side-effects though.

Comment: It might yeah... If I think of anything I'll let you know. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I've managed to get something working (see the answer I've just posted).

Comment: Have you ever heard of behaviors in WPF? Here is a [link](https://www.wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html) to a nifty little tutorial. Makes code a lot cleaner, custom controls in WPF never justify their existence other than whimsical side of their creator.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get this working by hooking up to the parent `Window`'s PreviewKeyDown event, which we can use to do whatever we want when someone presses `CTRL+V`.

```cs
//Note that the Parent property isn't defined until the UserControl is loaded
//So you can't do this in the constructor
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window parentWindow = FindParentWindow(this);

    if (parentWindow != null)
    {
        parentWindow.PreviewKeyDown += this.ParentWindow_PreviewKeyDown;
    }
}

private void listBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //By default a listbox does not get focus
    //So this allows user to give it focus
    //Would recommend adding something in the XAML to indicate when it has focus
    this.listBox.Focus();
}

private void ParentWindow_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //Check for IsFocused otherwise pasting into another control will paste
    //both in the other control and whatever you do in this method
    if (this.listBox.IsFocused && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key == Key.V)
    {
        //Do something with the clipboard
    }
}

//Recursively finds parents until it finds a Window or null
public static Window FindParentWindow(DependencyObject child)
{
    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
    return parent == null ? null : parent is Window parentWindow ? parentWindow : FindParentWindow(parent);
}
```

This works for my use case, however I can't promise it won't have weird effects if you hook up to PreviewKeyDown elsewhere.

I'd welcome and feedback/suggestions to improve this.

Thanks @EpicKip for the suggestion.